# panic: pq: password authentication failed for user "postgres" while adding the data into table through timescaledb-parallel-copy in hypertable

Tags: postgresql, timescaledb

I am using PostgreSQL with Linux 16.04 version. I installed timescaledb in that.

After words i am trying to insert huge data into the hypertable called `new_observation` through `observation.csv` it near by approx 5 GB data, while I copy by simply copy command I will get more error afterwords I see the another way to copy huge data from go-parallel copy so I just installed go and tried something like this:

```
go get github.com/timescale/timescaledb-parallel-copy
gopal@addontrack:~$ timescaledb-parallel-copy --db-name testat --
schema web --table new_observation --file /tmp/observation.csv \ --
workers 2 --reporting-period 30s
```

> panic: pq: password authentication failed for user "postgres"
>
> goroutine 19 [running]:
>   github.com/jmoiron/sqlx.MustConnect(0x641807, 0x8, 0xc42001e080, 0x3a, 0x0)
>   /home/gopal/.go/src/github.com/jmoiron/sqlx/sqlx.go:652 +0x83
>   main.processBatches(0xc420080250, 0xc42008a060)
>         /home/gopal/.go/src/github.com/timescale/timescaledb-parallel-copy/main.go:180
>   +0x63
>       created by main.main
>         /home/gopal/.go/src/github.com/timescale/timescaledb-parallel-copy/main.go:105
>   +0x178

when I try to copy data by this way i got this error.

Answer (score 3):

The postgres user by default has no password. But your server seems to expect password authentication.

The *timescaledb-parallel-copy* script assumes the default configuration for its connection defaults - but they can be overridden with the **connection** flag.

Default value:

```
"host=localhost user=postgres sslmode=disable"
```

New command (untested):

```
gopal@addontrack:~$ timescaledb-parallel-copy \
--connection host=localhost user=postgres password=super-secret sslmode=disable \
--db-name testat --schema web --table new_observation \
--file /tmp/observation.csv --workers 2 --reporting-period 30s
```